# Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and 164. Shapes are [8,128] and [8,164]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I got that problem when I used keras to try training virtual car to avoid obstacles

```
from flat_game import carmunk
import numpy as np
from nn import neural_net

NUM_SENSORS = 8


def play(model):

   car_distance = 0
   game_state = carmunk.GameState(display_hidden=False)

   # Do nothing to get initial.
   _, state = game_state.frame_step((2))

   # Move.
   while True:
       car_distance += 1

       # Choose action.
       action = (np.argmax(model.predict(state, batch_size=1)))

       # Take action.
       _, state = game_state.frame_step(action)

       # Tell us something.
       if car_distance % 1000 == 0:
           print("Current distance: %d frames." % car_distance)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   saved_model = 'saved-models/164-150-100-50000-625000.h5'
   model = neural_net(NUM_SENSORS, [128, 128], saved_model)
   play(model)
```

I got a problem in line

```
model = neural_net(NUM_SENSORS, [128, 128], saved_model)
```

Here is my neural_net function:

```
def neural_net(num_sensors, params, load=''):
       model = Sequential()
       print(params)
       # First layer.
       model.add(Dense(
           params[0], init='lecun_uniform', input_shape=(num_sensors,)
       ))
       model.add(Activation('relu'))
       model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # Second layer.
    model.add(Dense(params[1], init='lecun_uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # Output layer.
    # Output layer. 5 actions left, right, accelerate, decelerate, forward
    model.add(Dense(5, init='lecun_uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

    rms = RMSprop()
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=rms)

    if load:
        model.load_weights(load)

    return model
```

and i am getting this error when i run main in the first code:

> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2404, in call_with_requiring
>           return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 627, in call_cpp_shape_fn
>       require_shape_fn)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 691, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       raise ValueError(err.message)
>
> ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and
>   164. Shapes are [8,128] and [8,164]. for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [8,128], [8,164].

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: The model corresponding to the weights you are loading is different from the model shown here

Comment: The model weights you are loading have 164 neurons in the first Dense layer, while yours has 128

Comment: Sorry! Can you say more clearly !

Comment: Your weights dont match the model you are trying to load into. Error coming from first dense layer. it should have 164 neurons if you want to load weights

Comment: i changed it to [164,128] but it also error !